# Build disk images that would work both on BIOS and UEFI

Tags: centos, centos7, koji

[Ubuntu images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/20191210/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-uefi1.img) can boot both on BIOS and UEFI.

[CentOS8 Azure cloud images](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/blob/master/cloudimg/CentOS-8-x86_64-Azure.ks) are ready to boot on both BIOS and UEFI.

How would I build such an image with Koji for CentOS7? [CentOS7 cloud image is only BIOS ready](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/blob/master/cloudimg/CentOS-7-x86_64-Azure.ks)

My goal is to build a compatible [disk image with Koji](https://docs.pagure.org/koji/image_build/#building-disk-images) that can be used on both BIOS and UEFI, but so far based on CentOS7 kickstart, it only works on BIOS.

Is it actually possible to build one image for both or do I have to build one for UEFI on a UEFI machine with Koji and do the same for BIOS?

Comment: EDIT: Unless there is a better way it seems to be the case: https://gitlab.cern.ch/linuxsupport/koji-image-build/-/blob/master/cc7-cloud.ks